# Custom URL to Import Documents to iPad Excel

Tags: ios, excel, ipad, ms-office

Has anyone found the syntax to import a file to the new version of Excel on the iPad?   This can be done from the OneDrive app, but I can't seem to find any documentation that would explain the name/value pair that is required.   It is also unclear if Excel will open a file that is local to it;  it might be that all files must be in the OneDrive cloud.   Inspection of the info.plist shows that you can launch Excel from another app using any of the following urls:  launch-excel, open-excel, ms-excel, excel, but it unclear how you can pass a file to it and if the file could be a csv or other format.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any luck passing a file to open?

Comment: did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran over this question by myself. Downloaded the IPA (German version, v1.0.1: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/microsoft-powerpoint-fur-ipad/id586449534?mt=8) from the App Store and had a quick look inside the Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>com.microsoft.launch.ppt</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>launch-ppt</string>
        <string>powerpoint</string>
        <string>ms-powerpoint</string>
        <string>open-ppt</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
```

So the supported OpenURL-Schemes are: launch-ppt, powerpoint, ms-powerpoint, open-ppt.

Comment: But have we found a way to pass a file for it to open?
I'm trying ms-powerpoint:ofv|u|<filepath> to no avail :(